# How do I delete a bunch of files on my desktop using regex?

Tags: ruby

I'm messing around with ruby's scripting abilities, and as an experiment I created a ton of files with something like

```
1000.times do |i|
  File.open("text#{i}.txt", "w")
end
```

And now I want to delete them, using regex to match any file with "text" in the name (they're my only matching files on the desktop, don't worry)

I've tried

```
File.delete(Regexp.new("text.+txt"))
```

but ruby can't convert the regex to a string.

Is there a clever way to do this without another 1000 times do loop?

I've tried variations of this without success

```
Dir.foreach(Dir.pwd) { |f| f.delete if f =~ "/text.+txt/" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh, realized I was trying to call .delete on the file, but needed to use the File.delete class method. This is what worked:

```
Dir.foreach(Dir.pwd) { |f| File.delete(f) if f =~ /text.+txt/ }
```